# Can you call PHP from the command line and display errors to terminal, but without writing to error_log?

Tags: php, error-log

The folowing can be used to show errors on the terminal screen when you use PHP from the command line.

```
php -d display_errors=on filename.php
```

However, when I do this, it also creates or appends to a file error_log in that same folder.

Is there any way to turn the displaying of errors on, but disable writing to an error_log file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add error_reporting=E_ALL. I think this one should show you errors inside of cli instead of log file.

```
php -d error_reporting=E_ALL filename.php
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but then I no longer see the errors inside of cli, and I still get the error_log file.

Comment: it should be somewhere in php.ini, you can make your custom php.ini without changing the original one and run it with it. Sorry, I'm not sure now, but you can check this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096